# How to Run DDL on Snowflake SHOW <object<

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am not sure if it is possible but can you run DDL the SHOW Role function:

show grants to role SYSADMIN

If I run this it shows me the privs attached to the role in the results field but I would like to run a sub-query on this but it seems to always give me an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the rows in the `show` command directly (unless you're using an external client and programming the code, such as ODBC, JDBC, Python).

What you can do in a client worksheet is use the results indirectly like this:

```
show grants to role sysadmin;

select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

To use it in a query, just alias and reference it like a table:

```
show grants to role sysadmin;
show grants to role my_new_role;

select NR.* 
from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) NR
    inner join table(result_scan(last_query_id(-2))) SA
        on NR."privilege" = SA."privilege"
           and NR."granted_on" = SA."granted_on"
           and NR."name" = SA."name"
;
```

You can then use the age-old DBA trick of creating a SQL generator:

```
select 'grant ' || "privilege" || ' on ' || "granted_on" || ' etc.. etc...' as SQL_COMMAND
from table(result_scan(last_query_id()))
where "privilege" <> 'OWNERSHIP' 
;
```

You can even use an SP to automate execution of the generated commands:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Executing-Multiple-SQL-Statements-in-a-Stored-Procedure